# Small number calculation returns 0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

When I am trying to calculate a percentage, it returns 0. I have tried a demo where it works using numeric data type.

```
declare @percent int;
declare @test1 numeric = '5723897'
declare @test2 numeric = '52670845' 

select @percent = (@test1/@test2) * 100.0

select @percent
```

but as soon as I modify the numbers so there is a bigger difference I just get 0. How can I present this as a value? I have tried to cast as a decimal but this doesn't work.

```
declare @percent int;
declare @test1 numeric = '57238'
declare @test2 numeric = '52670845' 

select @percent = cast((@test1/@test2) * 100.0 as decimal(10,2))

select @percent
```

Any advice on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Integer division? Like 1/2=0. I..e try `(100.0* @test1)/@test2 etc`.

Comment: What other value would you expect for an `int` to show when the value you set it to is `0.11`?

Comment: As an aside, don't use `NUMERIC` without specifying scale and precision, and don't use quotes for numerical constants. Finally, for most calculations that don't need excess precision (and a percentage calculation typically qualifies) floating-point is easier than figuring out how scale and precision shift around (`(5723897e / 52670845e) * 100`); formatting the results should be a separate concern.

Comment: The issue isn't integer division.  The issue is that anything less than 1% will show up as `0`.  Unless you specify what you want done with those values, it is not really possible to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem: `declare @percent int;`

you're storing the result of the calculation in an `int` data type, so naturally you will get a truncated number - in this case - 0.

```
declare @intPercent int, @percent numeric(15,10);
declare @test1 numeric(10,0) = 57238
declare @test2 numeric(10,0) = 52670845

select  @percent = (@test1/@test2) * 100.0,
        @intPercent = (@test1/@test2) * 100.0

select @percent As [@percent], @intPercent As [@intPercent]
```

Results:

```
@percent        @intPercent
0,1086711250    0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @percent int;
...
select @percent
```

that variable is an `integer`. So values below `1` are `0`.

You could use a decimal data throughout all variables

```
declare @percent decimal(18,6);
declare @test1 decimal(18,6) = 57238
declare @test2 decimal(18,6) = 52670845

select @percent = @test1/@test2 * 100.0

select @percent
```

> Result: 0.108671

Or alternatively change the data type **early** during the calculation by introducing a decimal (`* 100.0`) in the first calculation step:

```
declare @percent decimal(18,6);
declare @test1 int = 57238
declare @test2 int = 52670845

select @percent = @test1 * 100.0 / @test2

select @percent
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to an int which does not support decimals.  You can make percent a decimal or you can multiply by more than 100. Check out the following code for ideas.

```
declare @percent int;
declare @percentdec decimal(30,20);
declare @test1 numeric = '57238'
declare @test2 numeric = '52670845' 

select cast((@test1/@test2) * 100.0 as decimal(10,2))
select @percent = cast((@test1/@test2) * 100.0 as decimal(10,2))
select @percentdec = cast((@test1/@test2) * 100.0 as decimal(10,2))

select @percent
select @percentdec
```